# How to enlarge boxes vertically?

Tags: spacing, boxes

I would like to enlarge vertically a box around a mathematical formula. I am looking for a generic way to do do, so that I could define a command to enlarge a box.

I would like to define commands `\boxedB{}` and `\boxedBB{}` that would add space in the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\boxed{ \
\left |\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx\right | \leq \sqrt{\int_0^1|f(x)|^2 dx}\cdot\sqrt{\int_0^1|g(x)|^2 dx}
\ }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to have more space above the `\sqrt{}` and below.

---

PS: It is not a problem if the command adds also space horizontally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can control the inner separation using `\fboxsep`.  Unfortunately, that’s for vertical *and* horizontal distance, but apparently you also wanted more distance to left and right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\boxedB[1]{{\setlength\fboxsep{10pt}\boxed{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\boxedB{
  \left |\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx\right | \leq \sqrt{\int_0^1|f(x)|^2 dx}\cdot\sqrt{\int_0^1|g(x)|^2 dx}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The definition of `\boxed` is not super-sophisticated, so we could also simpy extend it to take an optional argument which is the desired distance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\boxed[2][\fboxsep]{% by default take current \fboxsep
  {%
    \setlength\fboxsep{#1}%
    \fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#2$}% <-- original \boxed
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\boxed[10pt]{
  \left |\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx\right | \leq \sqrt{\int_0^1|f(x)|^2 dx}\cdot\sqrt{\int_0^1|g(x)|^2 dx}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Can I change this parameter locally?

Comment: (see edits to my question)

Comment: @Colas See updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can set separately the padding at the sides and at top/bottom:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xboxed}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { colas/xboxed } { #1 }
  \dim_set_eq:NN \fboxsep \l_colas_xboxed_tb_dim
  \boxed
   {
    \dim_compare:nF { \l_colas_xboxed_lr_dim = 0pt }
     {
      \hspace{-\fboxsep}\hspace{\l_colas_xboxed_lr_dim}
     }
    #2
    \dim_compare:nF { \l_colas_xboxed_lr_dim = 0pt }
     {
      \hspace{-\fboxsep}\hspace{\l_colas_xboxed_lr_dim}
     }
   }
  \group_end:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xboxedset}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { colas/xboxed } { #1 }
 }
\keys_define:nn { colas/xboxed }
 {
  lr .dim_set:N = \l_colas_xboxed_lr_dim,
  tb .dim_set:N = \l_colas_xboxed_tb_dim,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\xboxed[tb=9pt]{
  \left |\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx\right | \leq
  \sqrt{\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\,dx}\cdot\sqrt{\int_0^1|g(x)|^2\,dx}
}
\]
\[
\xboxed[lr=3pt,tb=9pt]{
  \left |\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx\right | \leq
  \sqrt{\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\,dx}\cdot\sqrt{\int_0^1|g(x)|^2\,dx}
}
\]
\xboxedset{tb=9pt}
\[
\xboxed{
  \left |\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx\right | \leq
  \sqrt{\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\,dx}\cdot\sqrt{\int_0^1|g(x)|^2\,dx}
}
\]
\[
\xboxed[lr=3pt]{
  \left |\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx\right | \leq
  \sqrt{\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\,dx}\cdot\sqrt{\int_0^1|g(x)|^2\,dx}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

If `lr` is not given a value, the same padding as top/bottom is used.

The setting is local for the particular `\xboxed` (and nested ones, of course, unless countermanded) or it can be set for the current group (or even document-wise in the preamble) with `\xboxedset`.

[image]

Comment: Wow! Your solution is very impressive!

Answer (score 3):

A non-framed version can be obtained by storing the content in a box, `\mybox`, and then adding a bar with extra height and depth in front of it. In this example `\mybox` is defined with `\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}` since it is supposed to be used in displayed math. The same approach can be used together with `\boxed` to not add horizontal space, or in other other boxes without the math declarations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\newdimen\myextraHT
\myextraHT=5mm
\newsavebox\mybox%
\newcommand\HTbox[2][\myextraHT]{%
  \savebox\mybox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}%
  \raisebox{-\dp\mybox-#1}{\rule{0pt}{\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox+#1+#1}}%
  \usebox\mybox
}
\begin{document}
A row of text to show where the box horisontal start and end
\begin{displaymath}
  \left |\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx\right | \leq \sqrt{\int_0^1|f(x)|^2 dx}\cdot\sqrt{\int_0^1|g(x)|^2 dx} 
\end{displaymath}
A row of text to show where the box horisontal start and end
\begin{displaymath}
  \HTbox{\left |\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx\right | \leq \sqrt{\int_0^1|f(x)|^2 dx}\cdot\sqrt{\int_0^1|g(x)|^2 dx}}
\end{displaymath}
A row of text to show where the box horisontal start and end
\begin{displaymath}
  \HTbox[20mm]{\left |\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx\right | \leq \sqrt{\int_0^1|f(x)|^2 dx}\cdot\sqrt{\int_0^1|g(x)|^2 dx}}
\end{displaymath}
A row of text to show where the box horisontal start and end
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get a framed version, as requested in the question, an `\fbox` can be added to the command:

```
\newcommand\HTbox[2][\myextraHT]{%
  \savebox\mybox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}%
  \fbox{\raisebox{-\dp\mybox-#1}{\rule{0pt}{\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox+#1+#1}}%
    \usebox\mybox}
}
```

Then the framed equations becomes:

[image]

Comment: Simply put `\fbox{...}` around `\usebox\mybox` and you have the frame as well.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, at some point I had something similar, but the `\rule` must also be included. I guess I wanted to show it in a more general way, and the frame looks a bit odd when space is added only vertically. Maybe I should have read the question one more time. I have edited the answer.