# Nice boxes for centered mathematical formulas

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

I would like to be able to highlight mathematical formulas by placing them in a nice box (with rounded corners and a background color).

So far, I have found this in my macros, but it is not working for centered formulas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\myBox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=blue!20,inner xsep=4pt, inner ysep=4pt, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=3pt,#1] {#2};\phantom{#2}}

\begin{document}

\myBox{Test}

\[
\myBox{\left |\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx \right |} % This does not compile
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Optional arguments

As in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348562/8323), if the command could take arguments like `\myBox[lr=3pt,tb=9pt]{...}` to change the `inner sep` or `inner ysep` it would be great.

Comment: `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}` and `\tcbhighmath{Test}`, for example ... The `highlightmath` style is configurable, or you could use `tcboxmath` instead, so changing the margins, colour etc. is no real problem then

Comment: I think this can help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237855/1952

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It compiles like a breeze (do breezes compile, really?) if you load the `empheq`  package. Don't load `amsmath` in this case: empheq loads `mathtools`, which loads amsmath. I took the opportunity to replace your pair of `\left| … \right|`  with an `\abs` command, which inserts a pair of `\left … \right` if  you use the starred version, or accepts an optional argument (`\big`, \Big`, &c.) for fine-tuning of the size. I also added some horizontal padding to your box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\myBox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=blue!20,inner xsep=4pt, inner ysep=4pt, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=3pt,#1] {\quad#2\quad\mbox{}};\phantom{#2}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert

\begin{document}

\myBox{Test}

\begin{empheq}[box=\myBox]{equation}
  \abs*{\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx } % This does not compile
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]